# Задан список целых чисел и целевое значение

Tags: python-3.x, list, python-3.6

Нужно получить список подсписков (или подмассивов),
сумма элементов которых равна целевому значению

Например,

заданы [10, 15, 20, 30, 40] и 45

получаем

[ [10, 15, 20] , [15, 30] ]

Подскажите, как можно реализовать?

Comment: Ну например... Цикл от 1 до размера списка. `itertools.combinations` для получения сочетаний. И каждое - суммировать и сверить с требуемым.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот пример решения задачи

```
   def subsetsWithSum(array, n, v, summa, res) : 

    # Если сумма=0 то подмножество найдено
    if (summa == 0) : 
        res.append(v)
        return


    # Если сумма не набрана, а элементы кончились
    if (n == 0): 
        return

    # Пробуем построить новое множество включающее или не включающее заданный элемент
    subsetsWithSum(array, n - 1, v, summa,res) 
    v1 = [] + v 
    v1.append(array[n - 1]) 
    subsetsWithSum(array, n - 1, v1, summa - array[n - 1],res) 




array = [10, 15, 20, 30, 40]
summa = 45
n = len(array) 
v = [] 
res=[]
subsetsWithSum(array, n, v, summa,res)
print(res)
```