# Оставить в числе только те цифры сумма, которых равна K. Остальные вырезать

Tags: php

Полностью задача звучит так: Для  каждого  числа  заданной  последовательности  натуральных   чисел   n0 ,n1,...,nm установить,  можно  ли  вычеркнуть  в  нем  некоторые  цифры, чтобы сумма оставшихся равнялась заданному числу к.

И забыл добавить: При решении задач запрещается пользоваться высокоуровневыми функциями и инструментами не предусмотренными главой задач. Запрещается пользоваться циклом foreach, если он предусмотрен изучаемым языком.

Всю голову себе сломал и чувствую, что уже иду куда-то не туда (исхожу из своего кожа)

```php
<?php
/*
Для  каждого  числа  заданной  последовательности  натуральных   чисел
n0 ,n1,...,nm установить,  можно  ли  вычеркнуть  в  нем  некоторые  цифры,
чтобы сумма оставшихся равнялась заданному числу к.
*/

//Функция сортировки цифр числа в порядке возрастания
function ascSortNumber(int $naturalNum): int
{
    $ascSort = $naturalNum % 10; //Переменная сортировки
    $naturalNum = $naturalNum/10;
    $pow = 0; //переменная степени т.к. работаем с разрядностью
    while ((int)($naturalNum) > 0) {
        // сравнение последней цифры числа с сортированным числом в разрядности сортированного числа
        if ($ascSort < ($naturalNum%10) * (10 ** $pow)) {
            $ascSort = ascSortNumber($ascSort * 10 + $naturalNum % 10);
        } else {
            $ascSort = $naturalNum % 10 * (10 ** ($pow+1)) + $ascSort;
        }
        $pow++;
        $naturalNum = $naturalNum / 10;
    }
    return $ascSort;
}
//поиск нужной суммы
function searchSum(int $numberCL, int $numberOfSum) : int
{
    $number = $numberCL;
    $lastNum = $number % 10;
    $sumOfNums = $lastNum;
    $number = (int)($number / 10);
    $resultNum = $lastNum;
    while ($number>0) {
        if ($sumOfNums + $number % 10 > $numberOfSum) {
            $number = (int)($number / 10);
            continue;
        }
        $sumOfNums += $number % 10;
        if ($sumOfNums == $numberOfSum) {
            return $resultNum * 10 + $number % 10;
        }
        $resultNum = $resultNum * 10 + $number % 10;
        $number = (int)($number/10);
    }
    return (int)($numberCL / 10) > 10 ?
        searchSum((int)($numberCL/10), $numberOfSum) :
        0;
}

//переворот числа
function reverseNumb(int $naturalNum): int
{
    $m = 0; //Будущее перевернутое число
    while ($naturalNum>0) {
        $m*=10;
        $m+=$naturalNum%10;
        $naturalNum = (int)($naturalNum/10);
    }
    return $m;
}

$N = 321;
$ascNum = ascSortNumber($N);
$searchNumb = searchSum($ascNum,6);
$reverseNumb = reverseNumb($N);


echo $searchNumb > 0 ? $searchNumb : "Нет цифр образующих сумму";
```

Буду рад любой помощи!

Comment: Вот ваша задача https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1060748/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%ba-%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bb-%d0%b8-%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5/1060761#1060761

Comment: Так в решении рекурсия. Это не высокоуровневая штука. Вам собственно переписать часть с добавления в массив

Comment: Если я вас правильно понимаю, мне в любом случае нужно будет узнавать длинну массива. А это как минимум сторонняя функция, использовать которую запрещено, да и массивы использовать мне тоже кажется, что не можно. Т.к. Остальные 28 задач решались без них

Comment: дак вы пишите на ассемблере тогда, чего вы этот пхп взяли. У вас в задаче написано "последовательность натуральных чисел". Как вы ее собираетесь представлять, коли как не массивом?

Comment: и как вы из той формулировки что дана, получили ту, что у вас в заголовке? почему вы от последовательности чисел, вдруг перешли к одному числу и цифрам в нем?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я более чем уверен, что решение кривое как моя жизнь... Но во всяком случае оно не нарушает условия, приведенные выше... Хотелось бы узнать возможно ли "это" как-то оптимизировать и избавиться от гов?№кода...

```php
<?php
/*
Для  каждого  числа  заданной  последовательности  натуральных   чисел
n0 ,n1,...,nm установить,  можно  ли  вычеркнуть  в  нем  некоторые  цифры,
чтобы сумма оставшихся равнялась заданному числу к.
*/

//Функция сортировки цифр числа в порядке возрастания
function ascSortNumber(int $naturalNum): int
{
    $ascSort = $naturalNum % 10; //Переменная сортировки
    $naturalNum = $naturalNum/10;
    $pow = 0; //переменная степени т.к. работаем с разрядностью
    while ((int)($naturalNum) > 0) {
        // сравнение последней цифры числа с сортированным числом в разрядности сортированного числа
        if ($ascSort < ($naturalNum%10) * (10 ** $pow)) {
            $ascSort = ascSortNumber($ascSort * 10 + $naturalNum % 10);
        } else {
            $ascSort = $naturalNum % 10 * (10 ** ($pow+1)) + $ascSort;
        }
        $pow++;
        $naturalNum = $naturalNum / 10;
    }
    return $ascSort;
}
//поиск нужной суммы
function searchSum(int $numberCL, int $numberOfSum) : int
{
    $number = $numberCL;
    $lastNum = $number % 10;
    $sumOfNums = $lastNum;
    $number = (int)($number / 10);
    $resultNum = $lastNum;
    while ($number>0) {
        if ($sumOfNums + $number % 10 > $numberOfSum) {
            $number = (int)($number / 10);
            continue;
        }
        $sumOfNums += $number % 10;
        if ($sumOfNums == $numberOfSum) {
            return $resultNum * 10 + $number % 10;
        }
        $resultNum = $resultNum * 10 + $number % 10;
        $number = (int)($number/10);
    }
    return (int)($numberCL / 10) > 10 ?
        searchSum((int)($numberCL/10), $numberOfSum) :
        0;
}

//Поиск цифры в числе
function isNumInResultNumber(int $numb, int $Num): int
{
    $result = 0;
    $pow = 0;
    while ($numb>0) {
       if ($numb % 10 != $Num) {
           $result = $result + $numb % 10*(10**$pow);
           $pow++;
       }
       $numb = (int)($numb / 10);
    }
    return $result;
}

//функция сборки конечного числа
function buildNumb(int $numb, int $numsOfSum) : int
{
    $pow = 0;
    $resultNumber = 0;

//поиск цифр суммы в числе
    while ($numb>0){
        if ($numsOfSum>isNumInResultNumber($numsOfSum, (int)($numb%10))){
            $resultNumber += ($numb % 10)*(10**$pow);
            $numsOfSum = isNumInResultNumber($numsOfSum, (int)($numb%10));
            $pow++;
        }
        $numb = (int)($numb/10);
    }

    return $resultNumber;
}

$N = 2342;
$K = 10;

for ($i = 1; $i<=$N; $i++){
    $ascNum = ascSortNumber($i);
    $searchNumb = searchSum($ascNum,$K);
    if ($searchNumb>0) {
        echo "$i ".buildNumb($i, $searchNumb)."\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вот такой вариант:

```
function subsetsWithSum($n, $summa) 
{
    # Если сумма=0 то подмножество найдено
    if ($summa == 0) {
        return 1;}

    # Если сумма не набрана, а элементы кончились
    if ($n == 0) {
    return 0;    
    }
    # Пробуем построить новое множество включающее или не включающее заданный элемент
    $res=subsetsWithSum(intdiv($n,10), $summa);
    if ($res==1){return $res;}
    $res=subsetsWithSum(intdiv($n,10), $summa - ($n % 10));
    return $res;


}
```

Comment: Решение интересное, но оно не решает проблему. Во всяком случае, я не вижу решения. Ваш код ищет числа, образующие сумму, но не вырезает остальные. Возможно я туплю и не соображаю адекватно и не вижу очевидного. Но все равно большое спасибо за ваше участие.

Comment: "можно ли вычеркнуть в нем некоторые цифры, чтобы сумма оставшихся равнялась заданному числу к" у вас требуется определить имеет ли число заданный вид. Вычеркнуть цифры это не ваша задача.

Comment: Т. Е. Нужно вывести числа для которых можно провести указанное вычеркивание. Сравните: вывести все числа, которые делятся на 3.